# Android KeyStore operation failed: Unsupported Digest

Tags: android, encryption, keystore

I'm having an error while decrypting data using the keystore on about 1% of my users (in different API versions and device models). The crash log is:

```
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed
       at es.xxxx.yyyy.utils.KeyStoreHelperManager.decrypt(KeyStoreHelperManager.java:256)
       at es.xxxx.yyyy.activities.MainActivity.checkKeyStoreCorrecto(MainActivity.java:308)
       at es.xxxx.yyyy.activities.MainActivity.configurarLayout(MainActivity.java:294)
       at es.xxxx.yyyy.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Caused by java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed
       at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:901)
       at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:926)
       at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
       at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89)
       at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265)
       at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2984)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2891)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1143)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1084)
       at es.xxxx.yyyy.utils.KeyStoreHelperManager.decrypt(KeyStoreHelperManager.java:251)
       at es.xxxx.yyyy.activities.MainActivity.checkKeyStoreCorrecto(MainActivity.java:308)
       at es.xxxx.yyyy.activities.MainActivity.configurarLayout(MainActivity.java:294)
       at es.xxxx.yyyy.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Caused by android.security.KeyStoreException: Unsupported digest
       at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:839)
       at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:926)
       at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
       at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89)
       at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265)
       at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2984)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2891)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1143)
       at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1084)
       at es.xxxx.yyyy.utils.KeyStoreHelperManager.decrypt(KeyStoreHelperManager.java:251)
       at es.xxxx.yyyy.activities.MainActivity.checkKeyStoreCorrecto(MainActivity.java:308)
       at es.xxxx.yyyy.activities.MainActivity.configurarLayout(MainActivity.java:294)
       at es.xxxx.yyyy.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

#0. Crashed: main
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2914)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This is the way we create the KeyPair:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
static void createKeysM(String alias, boolean requireAuth) {
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, SecurityConstants.KEYSTORE_PROVIDER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(
                new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                        alias,
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                        .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(1024, F4))
                        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                        .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256,
                                KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA384,
                                KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                        // Only permit the private key to be used if the user authenticated
                        // within the last five minutes.
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(requireAuth)
                        .build());
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        Log.d(TAG, "Public Key is: " + keyPair.getPublic().toString());

    } catch (NoSuchProviderException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This is the method we use to encrypt data:

```
 public static String encrypt(String alias, String plaintext) {
        try {

            KeyStore ks = KeyStore
                    .getInstance(SecurityConstants.KEYSTORE_PROVIDER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
            ks.load(null);


            //PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("alias", null);
            PublicKey publicKey = ks.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey();


            //PublicKey publicKey = getPrivateKeyEntry(alias).getCertificate().getPublicKey();
            Cipher cipher = getCipher();
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes()), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        } catch (NullPointerException  ex){
            Logs.logException(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Logs.logException(e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

And this is the method to decrypt data:

```
public static String decrypt(String alias, String ciphertext) throws IllegalBlockSizeException {
        try {

            KeyStore ks = KeyStore
                    .getInstance(SecurityConstants.KEYSTORE_PROVIDER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
            ks.load(null);


            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, null);


            //PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKeyEntry(alias).getPrivateKey();
            Cipher cipher = getCipher();
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(ciphertext, Base64.NO_WRAP)));
        }catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex){
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

The error is being launched while decrypting, just while doing cipher.init.

Our cypher is created like this:

```
private static Cipher getCipher() throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    return Cipher.getInstance(
            String.format("%s/%s/%s",
                    "RSA",
                    "NoPadding",
                    "BLOCKING_MODE"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a same experience like you. As my researching, I decide that the reason is that the users might be done unsufforted firmware update! (For example, android P (9) in Nexus 6P, Nexus 6p's final update was 8.0.1.) you have to look at that user device is support proper os version. Let me know your check, later.

Comment: Great, i agree with it